# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__blogapp_created_blog.user_id

Tags: django

I just created a simple childish model but it raise a unpredictable
error that is django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__blogapp_created_blog.user_id

enter code here

```
    from django.db.models import *
    from django.db import models
    class created_blog(Model):
        user=CharField(max_length=100)
        blog_title=CharField(max_length=100)
        blog_subtitle=CharField(max_length=100000000)
        date=CharField(max_length=100)
        blog_content=CharField(max_length=1000000000000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this model like this.

```
from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

In addition, I encourage you to read the documentation in terms of [`models`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#module-django.db.models) and [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/).

Comment: OneToOneField should be ForeignKey for this use case presumably

Comment: A trifle crept in with a rush, because in the meantime I was probably helping with the implementation of user profiles.